# Azure WebDeploy Failing

Tags: azure, webdeploy

I've been happily deploying my website to Windows Azure, but this morning I get the following error...

`Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("xxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)`

I can load the website and data is coming back from the WebAPI I have. I've looked at the link which suggests the following....

1. You can ping the remote machine
2. That the msdepsvc or wmsvc service
   is started on the remote server.
3. Your firewall is not blocking
   incoming connections of your ports on the destination. If you used
   the default installation, then it would be 80 for msdepsvc and 8172
   for wmsvc.

I've tried the ping, which doesn't work, but then a ping to the actual site doesn't work either (and the site works). As these are Azure servers I'm unsure how to check points 2 & 3.

Another site that I deploy to Azure has worked, so there must be something about this project

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed the issue, by upgrading from "Shared" to "Basic", and then switched back again, this must of caused some sort or reset at the MS backend.